# How can the repetition rate of mode-locked lasers be tuned?

Tags: laser

In my job there is a femtosecond mode locked laser. It is able to operate at a range of repetition rates. I understand the principle behind mode locking of a laser, but I do not know how it would be possible to change the repetition rate of the laser without changing the cavity length. How is that achieved in real applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cavity length (and therefore the mode-locked pulse repetition rate) of a laser can be changed in any of several different ways.  The easiest is to move one of the cavity mirrors using a piezoelectric stack.  Another is to insert a pair of optical wedges into the cavity and move them to vary the thickness of glass the beam must traverse.  The piezo stack is, of course, faster but has a shorter range.

The range of repetition rate adjustment depends on the total cavity length and the range of length adjustment.  It would be possible to put a "trombone" section into a cavity and obtain a very large repetition rate adjustment range.

Comment: I understood, thank you for the explanation. I do not understand how these optical wedges work? How would you increase the cavity length in a solid state laser?

Comment: For a solid state laser you would need an external cavity: mirrors that are not directly attached to the lasing medium.

Comment: Imagine a rectangular slab of glass between the gain medium and one of the cavity mirrors. The effective cavity length depends on the thickness of the slab.  Now slice the slab diagonally so it becomes two wedges that can be slid over each other to vary the thickness that the beam traverses.  That is how the optical wedge method works.  In a solid st as the laser it would be necessary to create a space between the gain medium ans a mirror, to insert the wedges.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the cavity length is exactly how it is done. I have a (mode-locked) Ti:sapphire oscillator in my lab with a repetition-rate stabilization system, which works by using a mirror on a piezo stage to tune the cavity length.

On the other hand, if you need a large change in rep rate, you could always use a pulse-picker, which essentially blocks some fraction of pulses to reduce the duty cycle of the laser.  The ones I’ve seen of this use an electro-optic crystal and a polarizer to controllably reject pulses.  This wouldn’t change the rep rate of the laser itself, but you could ultimately get a slower rep rate rate this way if that’s what you want.

Comment: Of course, I should ask, what is the system?  What’s the range of rep rate tunability?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I just didn't know how it would be possible to change the cavity length. Can you clarify a little more on how the piezo stage tunes the cavity length? Because I understand you can change the position of the mirror, but how do you increase the crystal? (Also the mirror can't be inside the crystal, right)

Comment: @DaniloLeiteRibeiro aah, I’m guessing your laser has a cavity which extends beyond the crystal, unless you have a monolithic semiconductor diode laser. In a solid state laser, the solid state crystal itself is the gain medium, and the cavity is defined by mirrors around the crystal. “Solid state” just means that the gain medium is a solid, rather than a gas (e.g. HeNe, CO2) or liquid (e.g. dye).

Comment: Oh I get it now! The gain medium remains the same, however the cavity length itself can also be composed of medium that does not provide any gain and that is what we increase to achieve different repetition rates. I got it! Thanks a lot